# Alternative to Microsoft Sync Framework 4.0

Tags: oracle, frameworks, synchronization

we are looking for a database sync framework which is platform independent. We target devices like wp7, iphone, blackberry, android etc. Syncfx 4.0 has this feature but it still in CTP stage.

what about Oracle Database Lite? Does it have support for synchronization with custom providers like syncfx 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Database Lite supports Blackberry, Android, Windows Mobile, and Windows 7/Vista/XP on the client side.

It is not interoperable with syncfx, but it can be used as a replacement for syncfx. It does require that you use Oracle Database for your backend data store. However if you can meet that requirement, then Database Lite could be exactly what you're looking for. It is a very powerful tool for synchronizing client SQLite or Berkeley DB databases with an Oracle backend.

You can download and try it out [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-lite/downloads/index.html).

Hope that helps, good luck with solving your problem.

Comment: we ended up writing our own sync framework. it wasn't very difficult